# How to show returned data on a Bootstrap Modal popup after submitting data in Yii2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2, pjax

I have a Modal popup that has two fields, the first one is to submit some information a do an internal query into a database, and the second field on that Modal popup is to show the returned data. However when I test independently (without being a Modal) it worked, however when tested as a Modal it only submit the data but not show any result on the same modal, what could be wrong? Thanks.

This is the view that calls to the Modal popup.

```
<?php Pjax::begin() ?>
        <p>
        <?= Html::button('Quick Search', ['value' =>Url::to('index.php?r=site/mypopup'),'class' =>'btn btn-success', 'id'=>'modalButton']) ?>
        </p>
        <?php
        Modal::begin([
        'header'=> '<h4>My Modal Popup</h4>',  
        'id' => 'modal',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
        ]);
        echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
        Modal::end();
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

This is the mypopup view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>

            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'mypopup-form', 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'pattern')->textArea(['rows' => 1]) ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'mypopup-button']) ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                     echo "<pre>";
                     //SECOND FIELD
                     print_r($model->data); 
                ?>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

This is the controller of mypoup:

```
public function actionMypopup()
    {

            $model = new PopupForm();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

                    $model->insertPopup();
                 return $this->renderAjax('mypopup', ['model' => $model]);

            } else {
                return $this->renderAjax('mypopup', ['model' => $model]);
            }   
    }
```

This is the js file:

```
$(function(){

    $('#modalButton').on('click', function(){
            $('#modal').modal('show')
                .find('#modalContent')
                .load($(this).attr('value'));
            }); 

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
         alert(xhr.getResponseHeader());
     });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have overcome the issue by modifying two parts:

First of all I have created a jQuery beforeSubmit method in the main.js file, so it wouldn't refresh the page and submit the form via ajax.

This code code goes below the previous code on the js file.

```
$('body').on('beforeSubmit', 'form#mypopup-form', function() {
    var form = $(this);
    if (form.find('.has-error').length) {
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: 'post',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $(form).find('.results').html(data);

    return false;
  });
           }
    });
```

Second, then after it will call the ajax to form action;  and in the view I have added a condition to check if its posting some data from ajax and then display the results in div name results.

This code goes above all the code on the mypopup file:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['MyPopupForm']))
                {
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($model->data); 
                    echo '</pre>';exit();
                }?>
```

and on the same file at the end:

```
   <div class="results"></div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```